# Squirrel appending "sql: " to errors, causing issues when error handling

Tags: postgresql, go, error-handling

Golang project: I'm using [Squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel) to generate SQL queries, and [pgx/stdlib](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx@v3.6.2+incompatible/stdlib) as a Postgres driver. I'm trying to account for a pretty common error, ErrNoRows, based on one of my queries, which is an acceptable error that I want to handle gracefully. The issue is pgx returns the error having text "no rows in result set", whereas Squirrel returns "sql: no rows in result set", so comparing them fails. Same text, just Squirrel is prefixing the error. What is the idiomatic way to handle this? I feel like substringing or replacing the "sql: " out isn't the appropriate way to go.

Comment: You should not be comparing the errors' string values, instead you should be comparing the error values themselves, and in the case of wrapped errors you should be using [`errors.Is`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) and co.

Comment: I will not address what you should be looking for. But if you use a tool, and that tool itself adds anything then your code **must** either accept that addition, handle it or you use another tool. In this case substringing out the undesirable element **is an entirely  appropriate** solution.  IMHO: Just accept it and move on.

Answer (score 2):

It's not squirrel prefixing the error, that is what `database/sql` has for `sql.ErrNoRows`.

For some reason, [`pgx`](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/3ab89419216bcaf306c930ce291ef2b63000ba08/conn.go#L95) does `ErrNoRows = errors.New("no rows in result set")`

But, since it's exported, you could just do:

```
pgx.ErrNoRows = sql.ErrNoRows
```

when your application starts up.  Or write a function

```
func IsErrNoRows(err error) bool {
    return errors.Is(err, sql.ErrNoRows) || errors.Is(err, pgx.ErrNoRows)
}
```